# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 CompareTo(System.String)' method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I want to compare 2 strings in my sql query. In this query I want all values bigger than a specific value. So in SQL this would look something like this `where STREET > 'street'`. In linq I used this in my where clause: `x => x.Street.CompareTo(_opsm.Street) <= 0`. However when I run this I get an error saying:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 CompareTo(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Does this mean I cannot use this comparer in EF?

EDIT: We use a [specification system](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670115/Specification-pattern-in-Csharp) in my where queries. I never had any problems like that before with it, but upon closer examination,  it might be related to them.

An example of a simple specification is this:

```
    var tempspec = new AdHocSpecification<Eenheid>(
                        x => string.Compare(x.Street, OverzichtPersonenSearch.Street, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0
                    );
```

This AdHocSpecification basically returns the Expression> immediately (code of AdHocSpec is [here](http://pastebin.com/JLz9dfci))

Strangely enough this works:

```
Een = (from ver in q1
        .Where(
            x =>
                x.PersoonsID == persoon.ComputerNr)
    join een in PagedView.Context.EENHEID
    on ver.Eenheid equals een.ComputerNr into h
        from een in h.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select een
).FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.Street, "02", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
```

But this does not:

```
Een = (from ver in q1
        .Where(
            x =>
                x.PersoonsID == persoon.ComputerNr)
    join een in PagedView.Context.EENHEID
    on ver.Eenheid equals een.ComputerNr into h
        from een in h.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select een
).FirstOrDefault(tempspec.IsSatisfied())
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy error does not say that. Int32 there is return type of CompareTo method. By the way that code works fine for me in EF6. What is the version of EF you are using?

Comment: We use EF6 as well. However this happens in a sub-select. Maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: What data provider are you using? `string.CompareTo` should work fine with the default SQL Server client.

Comment: Well better to just show the full query then. And provider is important (sql server, postgresql, mysql maybe?)

Comment: As an alternative you could try using `x => string.Compare(x.Street, _opsm.Street) <= 0`

Comment: Provider is SQL Server. And @DavidG I tried that too but it doesn't work. I'll update my question with more code in a minute

Comment: Are you using a non-standard provider then? Also which specific version of EF?

Comment: I use the default SQL data provider. I updated my question with more code

Comment: Your expression that works doesn't match the specification. What is `OverzichtPersonenSearch.Street`? Other than that the two code blocks are identical.

Comment: `OverzichtPersonenSearch.Street` is just a string, eg `"02"`. Streets are stored in our DB like "01 - foo", "01 - bar" , "02 - foo", "03 - bar" etc etc

Comment: If you replace `OverzichtPersonenSearch.Street` with `"02"`, does it work?

Comment: I get the same error then.

Comment: There must be something else you're not showing, the two codes blocks are effectively identical. Also, I'm not sure what the point of `AdHocSpecification` is in the first place, all it does is obfuscate your code.

Comment: `AdHocSpecification` exists because then I can use `&&` or `||` to connect a few specifications together. And I wish there was something I wasn't showing, but that's all there is to it. It directly returns the func. That's why the error makes no sense to me.

Comment: The only other thing here that might be at fault then, is that the specification uses the type `Eenheid` - are you 100% sure that `select een` returns that same type and not a derived one?

Comment: Yes select een returns an Eenheid.

Answer (score 1):

EF is translating your query into SQL and can only translate function calls that it explicitly supports, apparently `Int32 CompareTo(System.String)` is not supported.

Using the static method `string.Compare(string, string)` is supported: `string.Compare(x.Street, _opsm.Street) <= 0`.